# Emulate Html5 placeholder property in Scala Lift

Tags: javascript, html, scala, lift, placeholder

Is it possible to create using JsCmd + Jq and so one placeholder property on input tags?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, but there should be an easier way.  How about using the [Input Hint Overlay jQuery Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/inputHintOverlay) (or one of the many similar ones) and setting the 'title' attribute when binding the form element.

```
SHtml.text(name, name = _, ("title" -> "John Doe"))
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean to add js as a external file?

Comment: Yup, the js file is very small.